# How to set multiple fields as sort keys?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a DynamoDB table where I would like a combination of 3 fields to be unique (`user-id`, `subscription-name` and `year-month`). If I make `user-id` and `year-month` as partition and sort key it will not let me store `subscription-name` of Netflix and Hulu for the same month for same user.

Given all options and their trade offs, which one is the best? What are my options? I suggest combining subscription name with year using a delimiter (ex: `netflix:2023-06`).

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing your query patterns

Comment: I will query by passing a specific value for these 3 values and I expect there to only be 1 record with this 3 attribute combo

Comment: @btrballin you don't need Query for that, just GetItem.   And if that's your only access requirement, it doesn't matter what you use.  You could even do it without a sort key by using all three values together as a hash key... `userid:2023-06:netflix`

Answer (score 2):

Simply combine 2 fields for your sort key:

| pk | sk | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| userId | 2023-06:netflix | data |
| userId | 2023-06:hulu | data |

Notice that the sort key contains date first, this allows you to make queries like, for user1 give me all of their subscriptions in June 2023 for example, while still fulfilling your primary access patterns and handling uniqueness.

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE pk=user1 AND sk begins_with(2023-06)`